# "Publish" temporarily hangs my machine

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

A minor irritation at worst really, but still bugs me...

In MSCRM 2011, when I click the "Publish" link anywhere (Publish Entity, Publish Customisations etc..) I get the usual "Publishing customizations..." pop-up and everything works as expected, *however* this process causes my machine to semi-freeze. It's tricky to explain the exact symptoms, but essentially some applications hang until the publish is completed (Outlook 2010, Internet Explorer, Firefox at minimum).

Is this a common issue or have I (inadvertently) changed a setting on my machine which might cause such behaviour?

**Environment**

Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit running IE 9.0.8 64-bit, on a Dell XPS i7 / 8GB RAM.

---

I'm also thinking that this might be a Superuser.com question now I type this (but I know that CRM coverage is poor there). Vote me down if you must ;)

Comment: Very common in my experience - the publish process is essentially spitting out a very large XML file (or 3 if I remember correctly) which presumably grabs your processor's attention for the duration. I find I can't alt-tab either.

Comment: Cheers guys - I've been using this laptop for so long, I couldn't remember what it does on other machines. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Also I thought it odd since it didn't seem to affect the OS like high CPU often does. I'd got suspicions in the area of asynchronous processing etc. And thinking about it, the publish process should be server-side too so maybe it's not CPU. Anyway I'm not looking to necessaryily fix it now I know that we've all got the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same behaviour, so I suspect its working as designed.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use a separate program to handle publishing. I've never experienced a system hang using third party tools or my own solutions to publish various CRM elements. I'm guessing the problem is isolated to the CRM client. Jamie Miley has a good blog post on publishing, the C# portion of which I've posted below.

[How to: Publish All Customizations Using Jscript or .NET in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 With the PublishAllXmlRequest](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-publish-all-customizations-using.html)

```
PublishAllXmlRequest publishRequest = new PublishAllXmlRequest();
service.Execute(publishRequest);
```

---

On further reflection, the best way to eliminate the hang is to simply edit the Developer tab of the Application Ribbon and add a button that will call either javascript or C# code that will publish changes for the current item you're working on or all entities.

Depending on how complex your requirement is, this could be relatively easy. And of course this is all contingent on how annoying you find that wait to be.

Comment: Interesting observations Peter, thank you. I like the convenience and simple discrimination of the web UI buttons but when my patience on this minor issue wears thin it's good to know that there's at least an alternative out there that I hadn't cared to consider before now :)

Comment: @Greg: This can actually be done via the web UI (per my edit). Now your question gets an upvote for making me think about this.

Comment: lol - cheers Peter. In that case, +1 for inspiring what might (or might not - let's see if I get any time) my first blog posting in eons...